# blur not working on absolute inside absolute blur

Tags: css, css-position

I don't know what's happening when i set blur on an absolute div, inside an absolute div blur.

https://codepen.io/dalwick/pen/PoaoJOe

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="absolute-inside-absolute">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, blue);
  z-index: 200;
  backdrop-filter: blur(70px);
}

.absolute-inside-absolute{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 300;
  background: linear-gradient(green, transparent);
  position: absolute;
  backdrop-filter: blur(70px);
}
```

when you toggle blur on the third div, the blur on the second div was disabled

Comment: Could you describe more about what you expected to happen? To me it seems to be working so I’m not understanding what result you want.

Comment: i juste want a relative>absolute.blur>absolute.blur. when y do it : blur not working on .absolute-inside-absolute

Comment: okay, it works on safari but not on chrome :/

Answer (score -1):

```
 box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0,       0.1);
```

backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);

you can try code above

Comment: Thank's for your answer, 
but there are no changes when i add -webkit-backdrop-filter.
However, il don't want a box shadow, just a blur over blur